# Error while building elastic search from source

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, kibana

I am trying to build **elastic search** from source,
while executing `./gradlew :distribution:archives:linux-tar:assemble` got the error `Could not find org.elasticsearch.ml:ml-cpp:7.17.9-SNAPSHOT.`

complete error :

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':x-pack:plugin:ml:bundlePlugin'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':x-pack:plugin:ml:nativeBundle'.
   > Could not find org.elasticsearch.ml:ml-cpp:7.17.9-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://artifacts-snapshot.elastic.co/ml-cpp/7.17.9-SNAPSHOT/downloads/ml-cpp/ml-cpp-7.17.9-SNAPSHOT.zip
     Required by:
         project :x-pack:plugin:ml
```

I tried to replace version in the above link with latest version of elastic-search which works, but doesnt work for any older version than latest one.

Comment: have you also tried with `org.elasticsearch.ml:ml-cpp:7.17.9` ? no snapshot, I mean

Comment: nope, that is not working too :(